# Rails store method converts boolean to string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class that stores boolean attributes like so:

```
class Robot

  store :options, accessors: [:hairy, :smart]

  after_initialize :set_defaults

  private

    def set_defaults
      self.hairy ||= false
      self.smart ||= true
    end
end
```

I'm trying to update these booleans with a button_to method but my booleans are being converted to strings in the stored hash. My default is this:

```
#<Robot id: 3, options: {"hairy"=>false,"smart"=>true} >
```

But this:

```
<%= button_to 'Make hairy', robot_path(@robot, hairy: true), method: :patch %>
```

Turns "hairy" into a string:

```
#<Robot id: 3, options: {"hairy"=>"true","smart"=>true} >
```

I need to explicitly specify the new boolean value, so I don't want to loop through the params and toggle! How do I prevent values from becoming strings?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure at which point these being strings becomes a problem in your application but would overwriting the default accessors be a solution?

```
def hairy
  super.downcase == 'true'
end

def smart
  super.downcase == 'true'
end
```

There's more info in the Rails docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

Comment: It's only a problem because a string adds complexity and makes my robot class less pretty. As your answer implies, I can't simply call @robot.hairy. Your answer is definitely a potential solution - thanks!

Comment: I've just realised this isn't going to strictly work as is. The statement 'true'.to_i will still equal 0. I guess super.downcase == 'true' would work better.  Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I eventually decided on was this:

```
class Robot

  before_save :booleanize

  private

    def booleanize
      self.options.each { |k, v| self.options[k] = to_boolean(v) }
    end

    def to_boolean(str)
      str == 'true'
    end

end
```

The button will patch "true" or "false" as strings, but the before_save hook will go through each option and convert it to the corresponding boolean value.